# Bootstrap Datepicker can't not complete remove

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm from Japan.
Hope you can know my problem.

this is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ssnq31x4/)

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: '-6m',
  endDate: '+0d'
});

$('#txtIsGroupByMonth').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#datepicker :input").val("");
    $('.input-daterange,#ORDERDATE_B,#ORDERDATE_E').datepicker('remove');
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy/mm",
      viewMode: "months",
      minViewMode: "months",
      startDate: '-12m',
      endDate: '+0d',
      keyboardNavigation: false,
      forceParse: false,
      autoclose: true
    });

  } else {
    $("#datepicker :input").val("");
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker('remove');
    // $('.input-daterange').data('daterangepicker').remove();
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
      viewMode: "days",
      minViewMode: "days",
      startDate: '-6m',
      endDate: '+0d',
      keyboardNavigation: false,
      forceParse: false,
      autoclose: true
    });
  }
});
```

I want change start date and viewMode depend on checkbox.

When I change to viewMode to month.

I can't select dates six month before.

If I choose any month after 2016/1.

Then program work correctly.

Have anyone know what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answser;
Use 
`$(".input-daterange").datepicker('setDate', null);`
Instead of `$("#datepicker :input").val("");`

Then program work correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssnq31x4/1/

Answer (score 0):

For version 1.2.0 and newer, viewMode has changed to startView, so use:

`startView:"months"` instead of `viewMode: "months"`


http://jsfiddle.net/1643g2bm/3/

Hope this works.